# SonarQube links are outdated, how do I update them?

Tags: continuous-integration, sonarqube

After maven does some stuff via a jenkins job, you get a link to the project. This project (the current screenshot is skipping analysis in this case), has some links on the right-hand side.

[image: A screenshot of SonarQube, with the project name blacked out, and the relevant links circled in red]

In this case, "Home", "Continuous integration", "Bug Tracker" and "Sources". However, my links are outdated. And googling gives me nothing. Does anyone know how to deal with this?

If it helps, I am completely new to SonarQube. So if you knwo about an obvious fix, it's probably correct.

Update: Just so it's clear, the admin page does not let me do anything about these links. I ran grep -rniI "$offending-url" /opt/sonarcube to see if there were some configuration, but I just hit logfiles.
Here's a screenshot to show you what I mean.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote that you use Maven, so all data is defined in `pom.xml` file:

```
+------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|          URL           |           pom.xml element            |
|------------------------|--------------------------------------|
|          Home          |  project → url                       |
|------------------------|--------------------------------------|
| Continuous Integration |  project → ciManagement → url        |
|------------------------|--------------------------------------|
|      Bug Tracker       |  project → issueManagement → url     |
|------------------------|--------------------------------------|
|        Sources         |  project → scm → url                 |
|------------------------|--------------------------------------|
|  Developer connection  |  project → scm → developerConnection |
+------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Example:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    ...
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <url>http://www.example.org/</url>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/example/example.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:example/example.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/example/example</url>
    </scm>
    <issueManagement>
        <system>GitHub</system>
        <url>https://github.com/example/example</url>
    </issueManagement>
    <ciManagement>
        <system>travis</system>
        <url>https://travis-ci.org/example/example</url>
    </ciManagement>
    ...
</project>
```

You should update those nodes values and your project will display correct URLs after next analysis.

Comment: This works exactly as you suggested it would. Thanks a bunch man!

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of links

1. the ones you can add generally with sonar properties, there are just a few options
2. the links which you can set as an administrator

### Solutions

#### Links of the first type

1. if you want to change the one with sonar properties, you need to add them to your analysis. either by adding them as parameter directly to the call, or if you are using sonar-project.properties add them there

   ```
   sonar.links.homepage=<url>
   sonar.links.ci=<url>
   sonar.links.issue=<url>
   sonar.links.scm=<url>
   ```
2. or you can edit some of those for your whole sonar installation in `administration > General`

#### Links in the Link list

You can simple edit those for your projct in the `administration > links`. there you will have a list of all your links.

[image: links]

Comment: That's the obvious way to go, and I tried that. But there's no option for me to change those links in any way. It's still a good answer for others who come here by way of bing or what have you, so +1.

Comment: Yeah we delete and readd them always - have not found an edit button

Comment: Don't have either button though. I suspect they are automatically added somewhere, but I have no clue where. :S I can add new links though, if I needed to.

Comment: you actually do see the sonar properties beside the name.

Comment: updated the answer to also represent those sonar settings you are looking for